# New branch instead of push

Tags: git

I made some changes locally in my main branch and committed, but not pushed. Now, I changed my mind and I would like to create a new test branch, take all the changes that *would* be pushed, commit them to the new branch and remove from the main branch.

So (not a real output, wrote it by hand):

```
# get the code
git clone ...

# I am in the main branch
git branch
* main

# ...do some changes...
# and commit them
git commit --all

# I am ahead by 1 commit
git status
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit

# I changed my mind, I don't want to
# git push
# I want to move those changes to a new branch

git checkout -b test

# WHAT NOW?
# - move the changes that are "ahead" to the "test" branch
# - restore the main branch to the state before the commits
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changes "ahead" are simply those between `origin/main` and `main`. So, to reset `main` to its old state, you need to just `git reset --hard origin/main`. The full setup from WHAT NOW would be:

```
git checkout main
git reset --hard origin/main
```

...and that's it. Note that the first step of "WHAT NOW" is already done by `git checkout -b test`, so the only remaining step is restoring `main` to `origin/main`.

**NOTE**: this assumes that the changes have been *committed*, as stated in the question. Running `git reset --hard` on a checkout with uncommitted changes will make you **lose your changes**. If you are not sure whether the changes have been committed, run `git status`; after a successful commit, it will tell you that there is `nothing to commit`.

Comment: I thing i missed something... I did the `reset --hard` and it wiped out all the files that I worked on and did not commit them!

Comment: @JakubM. Don't forget that you're on the `main` branch, now restored to the state before the commits, as you requested. To get back to your files, issue `git checkout test`.

Comment: I didn't commit to `test` branch. Fortunately I had backup. Remember kids, commit your changed and do backups.

Comment: @JakubM. Ouch - glad you recovered your files!

Comment: @JakubM. Well, my answer is written under the premise that the files have been diligently committed, as stated in the question! And besides being explicitly stated in the question, committing often is always recommended when using git.